# How to remove form validation errors when the fields are generated with localstorage data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, local-storage

I have this form and i am trying to validate it a bit. When there is no input it should throw the message "this is required" and also disable the submit button. Its working fine,its throwing error messages if input fields are empty. Now what i am doing is i am saving those form fields data into browser localstorage and i am generating those fields from the localstorage when the user tries to fill up the form again. But the "this is required" message is still showing and the button being disabled even after the fields are prepopulated with cookies. How can i fix this?

```
</script>
      <script src="angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function cookies(){

    var fieldvalue = document.getElementById('rentname').value;
    var fieldvalue1 = document.getElementById('rentphone').value;
    var fieldvalue2 = document.getElementById('rentaddress').value;

    localStorage.setItem('text',fieldvalue);
    localStorage.setItem('text1',fieldvalue1);
    localStorage.setItem('text2',fieldvalue2);
  }

  function load(){
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
    var storedValue1 = localStorage.getItem('text1');
    var storedValue2 = localStorage.getItem('text2');

    if(storedValue){
      document.getElementById('rentname').value = storedValue;
    }

    if(storedValue1){
      document.getElementById('rentphone').value = storedValue1;
    }

    if(storedValue2){
      document.getElementById('rentaddress').value = storedValue2;
    }
  }
</script>


</head>
   <body onload="load()">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row" style="padding-top:2rem;">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <h2>Reserve Your Seat</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <hr>
         <form ng-app="rentalform" ng-controller="validateCtrl" method="post" id="rentalform" name="rentalform"     action="rentinsertdb.php" novalidate>
           <div class="form-group space" >
              <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter full name" name="rentname" id="rentname" ng-model="rentname" required>
                 <span style="color:red">
                  <span ng-show="!rentname.length">Name is required.</span>
                </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group space" >
              <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose your ride</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
                 <div class="dropdown">
                  <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="rentcar" ng-model="rentcar" required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your ride</option>
                    <option value="Toyota Alion 2008">Toyota Alion 2008</option>
                    <option value="Toyota Premio 2008">Toyota Premio 2008</option>
                    <option value="Toyota Corolla 2006">Toyota Corolla 2006</option>
                    <option value="Toyota Noah 2010">Toyota Noah 2010</option>
                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="rentalform.rentcar.$dirty && rentalform.rentcar.$invalid">
                 </select>
                 <span style="color:red">
                  <span ng-show="!rentcar.length">Please Select Your Car.</span>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!-- <div class="form-group space" >
              <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Number</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Enter phone number">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <p class="help-block"></p>
              </div>
           </div> -->
           <div class="form-group space" >
              <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Number</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
                 <input type="text" minlength="11" class="form-control" name="rentphone" placeholder="Enter phone number" ng-model="rentphone" id="rentphone" required>
                 <span style="color:red">
                  <span ng-show="!rentphone.length">Phone Number is Required.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <p class="help-block"></p>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group space" >
            <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
               <input type="date" class="form-control" id="focusedinput" placeholder="On Which date you would like to rent your ride?" name="rentdate" ng-model="rentdate" required>
               <span style="color:red">
                  <span ng-show="!rentdate.length">Date is Required.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
               <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
         </div>
           <div class="form-group space" >
            <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Profession</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Enter Institution/Profession" name="rentprof">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
               <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
         </div>
           <div class="form-group space">
              <label for="txtarea1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pick up address</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border"><textarea  name="rentaddress" cols="50" rows="4" class="form-control" ng-model="rentaddress" placeholder="Enter Full Address; For example: House#38, Road 7/a, Dhanmondi, Dhaka-1205, Bangladesh" id="rentaddress" required></textarea>

          </div>
          <span style="color:red">
              <span ng-show="!rentaddress.length">Address is Required.</span>
       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 space">
          <button class="btn-primary btn" style="background-color:#03a9f4; border-color:#03a9f4;" id="submitrent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-disabled="rentalform.$invalid" onClick="cookies()"> Confirm </button>
       </div>
     </form>
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Order Placed!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Your Order Has Been Placed! We will call you shortly!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>


</div>


 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">


$("#submitrent").click( function() {
     $.post( $("#rentalform").attr("action"),
     $("#rentalform :input").serializeArray(),
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
     });
     clearInput();
     });
     $("#rentalform").submit(function() {
        return false;
     });
     function clearInput() {
         $("#rentalform :input").each( function() {
            $(this).val('');
             });
         }
  </script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('rentalform', []);
    app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {

    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the entire document. Could you clean up and complete?

Comment: Actually the form the functions and validations everything is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make use of angulars ability to deal with forms. You can try this.

**Plunker** : http://plnkr.co/edit/sQWL0QPFNNsmVh4bXMUH?p=preview

**HTML**

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <label>* First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" class="input-text" type="text" data-ng-model="user.firstName" required data-ng-class="{'required-error':nameError}">
    <div data-ng-if="nameError" class="error-msg">First Name is Required</div>
    <br/>

    <input data-ng-click="submit()" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <button data-ng-click="loadLocalData()">Load Local Data</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  };
  $scope.nameError = false;

  localStorage.setItem('firstName', 'Harsh');

  $scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.myForm.firstName.$valid) {
      $scope.nameError = false;
      // make request here
    } else {
      $scope.nameError = true;
    }
  };

  $scope.loadLocalData = function() {
    $scope.user.firstName = localStorage.getItem('firstName');
    $scope.nameError = false;
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
  };
});
```

**Explanation**

1. Add name attribute to your form and add novalidate(will prevent default validations)
2. AngularJS will create an object on scope with form name ($scope.myForm here)
3. Add name attribute for inputs (will create objects with name like $scope.myForm.firstName)
4. On submit do validations and check for required fields
5. Reset error variables and set form to pristine on reset or loading local data (if you need)
6. Read The angularjs documentation for more https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the field outside Angular Scope, so you must tell Angular you updated it. Either by forcing a **$scope.apply()** either by updating the field with the LocalStorage inside Angular scope.